# Change Telerik Theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, styles

How can I change the default telerik theme for a RadTreeView. I have multiple elements and the RadTreeView doesn't follow the color style of the rest of the elements. Say I want to change it to Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the theme of a Telerik component, just set its Skin property:

```
tree_view_control.Skin = "Vista";
```

Is there something more here that I am missing?

Comment: This does work for the Telerik controls that I use. Check to be sure that you aren't setting the skin in two separate places (in the ascx and in the codebehind) - one will override the other. If all else fails, Telerik support is pretty good - they can probably help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was using the wrong control. I used a TreeView instead of a RadTreeView.

Answer (score 4):

In WPF Black theme is default. If you want to change it, first have DLL reference of theme you want to apply. Ex. Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows7.dll found in telerik install folder.

Use following code snippet for your app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Windows7Theme();
}
```